Pushing commits to github.com from a docker container
Goal: create a docker image for a vscode dev-container.
Context: Despite the ton of resources for such a topic available on the internet, I am experiencing troubles to figure out how to make users safely push to github.com from a vscode dev-container.
The host is Windows (latest), the container's OS is Ubuntu Jammy.
The key idea is to create a dev-container that is just as simple to use as WSL.
What I tried so far (perhaps not in the good way):

playing with ssh-agent
playing with gh auth login
playing with git credential manager

Ideally, I'd rather not copy the ssh keys into the container.

.devcontainer/devcontainer.json:
{
    "name": "devcontainer",
    "dockerComposeFile": "./docker-compose.yaml",
    "service": "dev_toolchain",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "shutdownAction": "stopCompose",
    "overrideCommand": true,
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/github-cli:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/sshd:1": {}
    },
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "settings": {
                "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
                "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": { "zsh": { "path": "/bin/zsh" } },
                "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true
            },
            "extensions": [
                // some extensions
            ]
        },
        "postCreateCommand": {
            "git-safe-dir-workspace": "git config --global --add safe.directory /workspace"
        }
    }
}

docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  dev_toolchain:
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: 'ubuntu:jammy'
      ssh: # requires ssh-agent service running on host
        - default
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined

And the Dockerfile installs various development tools.

Thanks for you time and help !
If some informations are missing, just ask me and I'll update this post.

[edit] For some reason that I'm trying to figure out, it started to work as expected (I can push commits to github.com successfully).

Without mounting nor copying the ssh keys.
But I setup:

a ssh-agent on the host side
a gcm (Git Credential Manager) on the host side



In the container:

running the command gh auth status from a terminale results in the following output: You are not logged into any GitHub hosts. To log in, run: gh auth login
the ssh-agent is not running / echo $SSH_AGENT_PID produce an empty output
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK produce the following output: /tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-<some_numbers>.sock

Is it possible that adding the following lines to the docker-compose.yaml file solved the issue ?
environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent


AFAIK mounting the SSH agent from a Windows into a Linux container is still not something doable, I am afraid.

You should be able to pass the keys as environment variables, though.

Rather than actually copying the keys in the container, you can mount them in the container (at "docker run" time).
Using a plain docker run command, you would do:
docker run \
    -v ~/.ssh/id_github.pub:/home/dir/.shh/idxxx.pub:ro \
    -v ~/.ssh/id_github:/home/dir/.shh/idxxx:ro ...


In a compose.yaml file, you can add these directives in the volumes: section:
  volumes:
    - ..:/workspace
    - path/to/key.pub:/path/to/home/.ssh/key.pub:ro
    - path/to/key:/path/to/home/.ssh/key:ro

You can even use environment variables there, e.g: to allow each user to specify the name of their github key:
  volumes:
    - ..:/workspace
    - path/to/${GITHUB_KEY_PUB}:/path/to/home/.ssh/key.pub:ro
    - path/to/${GITHUB_KEY_PRIV}:/path/to/home/.ssh/key:ro

As a setup step, this would just require to add 2 extra lines in the .env file on a developer's station:
# set the file names for your actual ssh keys:
GITHUB_KEY_PUB=id_ecdsa_github.pub
GITHUB_KEY_PRIV=id_ecdsa_github

